# WIX run sqlcmd during uninstall

Tags: wix

I have a wix installer that installs a sqlclr into a database. I'm using sqlcmd to run a script.

I would also like to remove the sqlclr when the user removes the application.
this is what i have so far and it does not seem to work.

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="sqlcmd.install" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <!--Ensure this runs after the CA to set up the property for its cmd line-->
  <Custom Action="sqlcmd" After="sqlcmd.install">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="NewerVersion" After="FindRelatedProducts">NEWERVERSIONDETECTED</Custom>
  <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize" />
  <Custom Action="sqlcmd.uninstall" After="InstallInitialize">Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<!--Find sqlcmd.exe path-->
<Property Id="SQLBINDIR">
  <RegistrySearch Id="SqlBinDir" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ClientSetup" Name="Path" Type="raw" />
</Property>
<!--Need to use "property" CA to get variable substitution-->
<CustomAction Id="sqlcmd.install" Property="sqlcmd" Value="&quot;[SQLBINDIR]sqlcmd.exe&quot; -S [SQLSERVER] -d [SQLDATABASE] -U [SQLUSER] -P [SQLPASSWORD] -i &quot;[#Install.sql]&quot; -v PROGRAMDIR=&quot;[APPLICATIONFOLDER]&quot;" />
<!--Note that the cmd line and args will come from a property with the same name as the CA, this has been set by the CA above-->
<CustomAction Id="sqlcmd" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Return="check" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="yes" />
<CustomAction Id="sqlcmd.uninstall" Property="sqlcmd" Value="&quot;[SQLBINDIR]sqlcmd.exe&quot; -S [SQLSERVER] -d [SQLDATABASE] -U [SQLUSER] -P [SQLPASSWORD] -i &quot;[#Uninstall.sql]&quot;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the fix for anyone interested.

Seems my uninstall was encountering the chicken or the egg issue.
my uninstall.sql file was removed before the sqlcmd was executed.
So i changed the uninstall to occure before RemoveFiles.

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>

  <Custom Action="installcmd.install" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <!--Ensure this runs after the CA to set up the property for its cmd line-->
  <Custom Action="installcmd" After="installcmd.install">NOT Installed</Custom>

  <Custom Action="uninstallcmd.uninstall" Before="RemoveFiles">Installed AND NOT REINSTALL</Custom>
  <!--Ensure this runs after the CA to set up the property for its cmd line-->
  <Custom Action="uninstallcmd" After="uninstallcmd.uninstall">Installed AND NOT REINSTALL</Custom>

  <Custom Action="NewerVersion" After="FindRelatedProducts">NEWERVERSIONDETECTED</Custom>
  <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize"/>

</InstallExecuteSequence>



<!--Find sqlcmd.exe path-->
<Property Id="SQLBINDIR">
  <RegistrySearch Id="SqlBinDir" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\ClientSetup" Name="Path" Type="raw" />
</Property>

<!--Need to use "property" CA to get variable substitution-->
<CustomAction Id="installcmd.install" Property="installcmd" Value="&quot;[SQLBINDIR]sqlcmd.exe&quot; -S [SQLSERVER] -d [SQLDATABASE] -U [SQLUSER] -P [SQLPASSWORD] -i &quot;[#Install.sql]&quot; -v PROGRAMDIR=&quot;[PROGRAMDIR]&quot;" />
<!--Note that the cmd line and args will come from a property with the same name as the CA, this has been set by the CA above-->
<CustomAction Id="installcmd" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Return="check" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="yes" />

<CustomAction Id="uninstallcmd.uninstall" Property="uninstallcmd" Value="&quot;[SQLBINDIR]sqlcmd.exe&quot; -S [SQLSERVER] -d [SQLDATABASE] -U [SQLUSER] -P [SQLPASSWORD] -i &quot;[#Uninstall.sql]&quot;" />
<!--Note that the cmd line and args will come from a property with the same name as the CA, this has been set by the CA above-->
<CustomAction Id="uninstallcmd" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Return="check" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="yes" />
```